# HostingEnvironment does not contain a definition for IsHosted

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm developing a C# application and I need to find out if I'm under IIS or not. I've seen some question on SO about using the `HostingEnvironment.IsHosted` method. Unfortunately if I write something like:

```
if (HostingEnvironment.IsHosted)
{
    // on IIS
}
else
{
   // not on IIS
}
```

I get a compile error:

> HostingEnvironment does not contain a definition for IsHosted

I'm using:
`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;`
`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal;`

**EDIT**

Tried using `System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.IsHosted` as suggested but it didn't work

[image]

Comment: You are mixing framework versions. System.Web is no longer used in asp.net-core

Comment: ok, what could I use instead?

Comment: Check the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/hosting?tabs=aspnetcore1x

Comment: I already had a look at it but nothing seems to explain how to do it

Comment: No one has an idea how to do it?

Comment: I don't think that is how it works. You are the one starting up the service so you are the one determining whether it is using IIS or not.

Comment: I'll go for a command line parameter then...

Comment: That would be a viable solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might help. You could fetch the `IHostingEnvironment` like this:

```
var hostingEnvironment =(IHostingEnvironment)options.ApplicationServices.GetService(typeof(IHostingEnvironment))

if(hostingEnvironment.IsProduction())
{
    // do work
}
```

The environment is set in your `launchSettings.json`. Under your launch profiles:

```
"IIS Express": {
  "commandName": "IISExpress",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "launchUrl": "/api/values",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  }
},
```

Default value is "Production" when deployed.

EDIT: I'm actually missing a portion. You would be required to envelope code in `.UseKestrel(options => {   /* environment code */ })`

Comment: thanks but I don't quite follow you.. what does it mean to envelope the code in x?

Comment: place `var hostingEnvironment = ....` that I posted inside of your `new WebHostBuilder().UseKestrel(options => { /*place here*/ });`

Comment: then you can use your if block from your question

Answer (score 0):

What you mean is `System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.IsHosted`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.ishosted(v=vs.110).aspx

Not sure what's the ASP.NET Core equivalent.

Comment: tried System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.IsHosted but "Hosting" does  not exist.. see my edit